# How to query flink's queryable state

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using flink 1.8.0 and I am trying to query my job state.

```
val descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor("myState", Types.CASE_CLASS[Foo])
    descriptor.setQueryable("my-queryable-State")
```

I used port 9067 which is the default port according to [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/configuration/QueryableStateOptions.html), my client:

```
val client = new QueryableStateClient("127.0.0.1", 9067)
val jobId = JobID.fromHexString("d48a6c980d1a147e0622565700158d9e")

      val execConfig = new ExecutionConfig
       val descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor("my-queryable-State", Types.CASE_CLASS[Foo])
      val res: Future[ValueState[Foo]] = client.getKvState(jobId, "my-queryable-State","a", BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, descriptor)
      res.map(_.toString).pipeTo(sender)
```

but I am getting :

```
[ERROR] [06/25/2019 20:37:05.499] [bvAkkaHttpServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(bvAkkaHttpServer)] Error during processing of request: 'org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9067'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9067
```

1. what am I doing wrong ?
2. how and where should I define `QueryableStateOptions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So If You want to use the `QueryableState` You need to add the proper Jar to Your flink. The jar is `flink-queryable-state-runtime`, it can be found in the `opt` folder in Your flink distribution and You should move it to the `lib`  folder.

As for the second question the `QueryableStateOption` is just a class that is used to create static `ConfigOption` definitions. The definitions are then used to read the configurations from `flink-conf.yaml` file. So currently the only option to configure the `QueryableState` is to use the flink-conf file in the flink distribution.

EDIT: Also, try reading this][1](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html) it provides more info on how does Queryable State works. You shouldn't really connect directly to the server port but rather You should use the proxy port which by default is `9069`.

Comment: Thanks, I did flowed the instruction above and restarted the flink cluster (standalone ) BUT still getting connection refused error :
```Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9067
```

Comment: Hey, I have added the edits :) Also, verify in the logs of jobmanager and taskmanagers whether there is information about starting the Queryable State Proxy.

Comment: I set everything as described https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html and I do see in the logs "Started the Queryable State Proxy Server @ ...". but still getting connection refused

Comment: Hey, 
how are You starting You cluster ? Are You using Docker or some other way ?? Also Are you using the correct port ?

Comment: this is running on my local machine. I start the cluster simply by `flink/bin/start-cluster.sh`

Comment: The problem was that the client didn't address the proxy server (as reported in the log `Started Queryable State Proxy Server ... `)just the correct port